# adding file by ajax - using rest API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

When using this code for adding files:

```
 $("#getFile").on('change', function () {
    var idVal = $("#" + itemID).val();
    var files = this.files;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists('" + guidList + "')/items",            
        method: "POST",
        ....

    });

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[x];
            var lastFileName = file.name;
            if (!checkIfExist(filesItems, lastFileName)) {
                var fileName = Date.now() + file.name;
                var getFileBuffer = function (file) {
                    //alert('in getFileBuffer');
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
                    }
                    reader.onerror = function (e) {
                        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
                    }
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                    return deferred.promise();
                }


                getFileBuffer(file).then(function (buffer) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists('" + guidList + "')/items('" + idVal + "')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName = '" + fileName + "')",
                        method: 'POST',
                        ....

    })
```

I get an error for sending a post to this address: .../_api/web/lists('9d082dbb-217c-4abb-922f-807d0f6d5dce')/items('22')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName = 'fileName')

Do you know how to use rest API for adding attachments to a specific file by the list guid?

(When using by list name - it works)

Comment: `add(FileName = '" + fileName + "')"` why do you have spaces before and after FileName. It should be `add(FileName='" + fileName + "')"`

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past.

```
"/_api/web/lists(guid'" + guidList + "')/items"
```

Comment: Could you reflect that in the vote?

Comment: I have problem in voting because my reputation is 6

Comment: Can't up vote in your own post?